# How to find rows with multiple special letter in string column? (Pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to find rows with multiple special letter in pandas dataframe

original dataframe has 10,000rows and 300 columns

Here is the sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'EVENT_DTL': ['5. Method/Means: Pesticide_Agriculture_Bentazone|Pesticide_Geunsami_Glyphosate-Isopropylamine|Pesticide_Elsan_Pentoate|Pesticide_Procure_Cyanthraniliprol|Pesticide_Valigan_Glyphosate Ammonium|Pesticide_Spreading agent_Kava_999','5. Method/Method: Jumping_1517-4 Dangu-dong, Wonju-si, Gangwon-do Hyundai Apartment Building 101, Room 1002 Veranda Window','5. Method/method: Jumping_Rooftop on the 25th floor, Line No. 3, Building 1043, Cheonggwang Plus One, 640 Seochang-dong, Namdong-gu, Incheon','5. Method/Means: Pesticide_Conido_Imidacloprid|Pesticide_Decis_Deltamethrin|Pesticide_Samgondimetho_Dimethoate|Pesticide_Bigcard_Clotianidin|Pesticide_999_999|Pesticide_Save_Chlorotalo Neil|Pesticide_Caris_Imidacloprid']})
```

which looks like this:

```
EVENT_DTL
0   5. Method/Means: Pesticide_Agriculture_Bentazone|Pesticide_Geunsami_Glyphosate-Isopropylamine|Pesticide_Elsan_Pentoate|Pesticide_Procure_Cyanthraniliprol|Pesticide_Valigan_Glyphosate Ammonium|Pesticide_Spreading agent_Kava_999
1   5. Method/Method: Jumping_1517-4 Dangu-dong, Wonju-si, Gangwon-do Hyundai Apartment Building 101, Room 1002 Veranda Window
2   5. Method/method: Jumping_Rooftop on the 25th floor, Line No. 3, Building 1043, Cheonggwang Plus One, 640 Seochang-dong, Namdong-gu, Incheon
3   5. Method/Means: Pesticide_Conido_Imidacloprid|Pesticide_Decis_Deltamethrin|Pesticide_Samgondimetho_Dimethoate|Pesticide_Bigcard_Clotianidin|Pesticide_999_999|Pesticide_Save_Chlorotalo Neil|Pesticide_Caris_Imidacloprid
```

My purpose is to split '|', and find columns which contain '_' more than two, and get rid off the last _OOO string.

so this sample dataframe index 0 should be like this:

```
5. Method/Means: Pesticide_Agriculture_Bentazone|Pesticide_Geunsami_Glyphosate-Isopropylamine|Pesticide_Elsan_Pentoate|Pesticide_Procure_Cyanthraniliprol|Pesticide_Valigan_Glyphosate Ammonium|Pesticide_Spreading agent_Kava
```

you can see change `Pesticide_Spreading agent_Kava_999 -> Pesticide_Spreading agent_Kava`

Comment: I don't understand why you need a split, but I assume you can simply use this `df['is_special'] = df['EVENT_DTL'].apply(lambda x : x.count('_') > 2)`. Also, you mention multiple columns, but there is only one column in your sample besides the index.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis Cause I just need to correct one column not others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import re

df = pd.merge(df, df.EVENT_DTL.str.split('|', expand=True),
              left_index=True, right_index=True)
results = df.apply(lambda x: [re.sub('_\d+$', '', cell) if cell is not None and cell.count(
    '_') > 2 else None for cell in x], axis=1, result_type='expand')
results.columns = df.columns
results
```

I've made an additional table with results that solves your issue, but may need some additional formatting.

| EVENT_DTL | 0 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5. Method/Means: Pesticide_Agriculture_Bentazo... | None | None | None | None | Pesticide_Spreading agent_Kava | None |
| None | None | None | None | None | None | None |
| None | None | None | None | None | None | None |
| 5. Method/Means: Pesticide_Conido_Imidacloprid... | None | None | None | None | None | None |

This code splits by |, than filters by _ count and removes trailing _number.